# directory globbing with partitioned dask read_parquet directories

Tags: pandas, dask, parquet, pyarrow, dask-dataframe

I have a directory of partitioned weather station readings that I've written with `pandas`/`pyarrow`.

```py
c.to_parquet(path=f"data/{filename}.parquet", engine='pyarrow', compression='snappy', partition_cols=['STATION', 'ELEMENT'])
```

When I attempt to read a handful of files back with a glob and predicate pushdown clauses like below

```py
ddf= dd.read_parquet("data/*.parquet", engine='pyarrow', gather_statistics=True, filters=[('STATION', '==', 'CA008202251'), ('ELEMENT', '==', 'TAVG')], columns=['TIME','ELEMENT','VALUE', 'STATION'])
```

I get an index error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, gather_statistics, split_row_groups, read_from_paths, chunksize, aggregate_files, **kwargs)
    314         gather_statistics = True
    315 
--> 316     read_metadata_result = engine.read_metadata(
    317         fs,
    318         paths,

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py in read_metadata(cls, fs, paths, categories, index, gather_statistics, filters, split_row_groups, read_from_paths, chunksize, aggregate_files, **kwargs)
    540             split_row_groups,
    541             gather_statistics,
--> 542         ) = cls._gather_metadata(
    543             paths,
    544             fs,

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py in _gather_metadata(cls, paths, fs, split_row_groups, gather_statistics, filters, index, dataset_kwargs)
   1786 
   1787         # Step 1: Create a ParquetDataset object
-> 1788         dataset, base, fns = _get_dataset_object(paths, fs, filters, dataset_kwargs)
   1789         if fns == [None]:
   1790             # This is a single file. No danger in gathering statistics

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py in _get_dataset_object(paths, fs, filters, dataset_kwargs)
   1740         if proxy_metadata:
   1741             dataset.metadata = proxy_metadata
-> 1742     elif fs.isdir(paths[0]):
   1743         # This is a directory.  We can let pyarrow do its thing.
   1744         # Note: In the future, it may be best to avoid listing the

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can load the parquet directories individually

```py
ddf= dd.read_parquet("data/2000.parquet", engine='pyarrow', gather_statistics=True, filters=[('STATION', '==', 'CA008202251'), ('ELEMENT', '==', 'TAVG')], columns=['TIME','ELEMENT','VALUE', 'STATION'])
```

Is globbing possible with `dask`/`parquet`/`pyarrow` reads?

Answer (score 2):

When using `partition_cols` in `.to_parquet`, the partitioned dataframes are saved in separate files, so `data/2000.parquet` in your case is likely a folder.

```py
import pandas as pd
from os.path import isdir

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(range(3), columns=['a'])
df['b'] = df['a']
df['c'] = df['a']

# save without partitioning
df.to_parquet('test.parquet')
print(isdir('test.parquet')) # False

# save with partitioning
df.to_parquet('test_partitioned.parquet', partition_cols=['a', 'b'])
print(isdir('test_partitioned.parquet')) # True
```

As a way out of this, it might be a good solution to construct an explicit list of parquet files with `os.walk` or `glob`. Note that if there are multiple partition columns, then there will be multiple nested folders with parquet files, so a simple glob will not be sufficient and you will want to do a recursive search.

Alternatively, one can construct `dask.dataframes` for each year and then concatenate them with `dd.concat`.

Comment: The workaround did work - but how does one prevent this during the `to_parquet()` write stage?

Comment: Do you mean writing multiple partitions to a single parquet? It's a bit tricky, I don't think 'append' operation is easy with parquet format (maybe not possible).

Comment: To elaborate on the previous point, if the dataframe fits into memory, then it can be written into a single parquet (by converting it to pandas via .compute), but writing a dask dataframe to a single parquet... I don't think that's possible to do directly.

Answer (score 1):

The `"data/*.parquet"` part is probably what's causing you issues.  You need to provide the root paths to your partitioned lake without the `*`.

Here's an example code snippet that works:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["north america", "mexico", "carlos"],
        ["asia", "india", "ram"],
        ["asia", "china", "li"],
    ],
    columns=["continent", "country", "first_name"],
)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
ddf.to_parquet(
    "tmp/partition/2", engine="pyarrow", partition_on=["continent", "country"]
)

ddf = dd.read_parquet(
    "tmp/partition/2",
    engine="pyarrow",
    filters=[("continent", "==", "asia"), ("country", "==", "china")],
)
```

Notice that `read_parquet` is being called on `"tmp/partition/2"`, not a directory with an asterisk.